# Angular select, ng-init with dynamic value

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to get a select box working in Angular. The problem I'm experiencing is to do with ng-init and setting it's default value from an object which is created during runtime. Heres my code:

```
        <select 
            ng-model="settings.editing.panel.data.production_company"
            ng-change="settings.editing.panel.data.production_company = selectValue"
            ng-init="selectValue = settings.editing.panel.data.production_company"  
        >
            <option 
                ng-repeat="(key, value) in lists.production_companies" 
                value="{{key}}"
                ng-selected="{{selectValue}}" 
                >
                    {{value}}
                </option>
        </select>
```

"lists.production_companies" is a simple key-value array of names, populated during initial page render, updated by ajax.

The object "settings.editing.panel.data" starts its life as NULL, but later is loaded with a correctly formatted object which contains the property "production_company".

I have found setting ng-init to something like "ng-init="selectValue = 3" works fine. Setting a $scope.test = 3, then setting "ng-init="selectValue = test" works fine too.

However, my dynamic value does not work. How can I use my dynamically created object to set the value of this select box during runtime with the set-up I have?

Comment: use ngOptions instead ngRepeat for select

Comment: Why you use ng-model if you will maintain the value with ng-change? Read about the work of ng-model in select component

Comment: It was part to do with my misunderstanding, and part to do with the model not working for a still unknown reason. I have since solved this by reworking the problem. In this case my model was not being set initially if the model was being loaded in after start of run time via ajax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my circumstances I was able to change my backends data format to set an object like:

```
{"id": 1, "name":"prod comp 1"}
```

and then change my select model accordingly. In hindsight I needed this for the ID anyway.

```
<select 
    ng-model="settings.editing.panel.data.production_company"
>
    <option 
        ng-repeat="option in settings.lists.production_companies" 
        value="{{option.id}}"
        ng-selected="{{option.id}} == settings.editing.panel.data.production_company"
    >
        {{option.name}}
    </option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

You question confused me somehow. The following snippet is a `working` one, is that what you want?

```js
'use strict';
angular.module('DemoApp', []);
angular.module('DemoApp').controller('DemoCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){
  $scope.lists={
   production_companies: { "0": "prod 1", "1":"prod_2" },
  };
  $scope.settings={
   editing: {
     panel: {
       data: null
      }
    }
  };
  $scope.setData=function(data){
    $scope.settings.editing.panel.data={
      production_company: data
    };
  };
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="DemoApp" ng-controller="DemoCtrl">
<select ng-model = "settings.editing.panel.data.production_company">
  <option ng-repeat = "(key, value) in lists.production_companies" value = "{{key}}">{{value}}</option>
</select>
<div>You select: {{settings.editing.panel.data.production_company}}</div>
<button ng-click="setData('0')">Set Data to Prod1</button>
<button ng-click="setData('1')">Set Data to Prod2</button>
</div>
```

Comment: settings.editing.panel.data is set during an button click like this: "$scope.settings.editing.panel.data = angular.copy(object)", just so I understand, is this likely to be the cause of the <select> problem? I've read info on that page, but I'm not following how to achieve this in my code.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select 
            ng-model="settings.editing.panel.data.production_company"
            ng-options = "option as option.keyName for option in list.production_companies"
        > <!--set keyName equal to your object's key-->

        </select>
```

Then in your controller

```
$scope.settings.editing.panel.data.production_company = list.production_companies[0] // Or which value you want to assign
```

Comment: I tried this method but got stuck on syntax as my production_company list is formatted as a simple key value, i.e.:
list.production_companies = { "0": "prod 1", "1":"prod_2" };

Comment: then why don't you create a new scope to assign the model in the view ?
e.g. `$scope.selectedCompany = $scope.list.production_companies[0]`

Then in your view `ng-model="selectedCompany"`